Keras Model: Input Shape Mismatch Issue After Debugging Dimensions
0
I have a multi-input Keras model combining a text input and a numeric input. Both inputs are passed through Dense layers followed by Embedding layers, then concatenated and pooled using GlobalMaxPooling1D. Despite thorough debugging of layer dimensions at each step, I still encounter an error when feeding data into the model.
Here is the model definition:
def model_builder(hp, vocab_size, max_token_size):
# Hiperparametre tanımları
hp_text_units = hp.Int('text_units', min_value=64, max_value=512, step=32)
hp_numeric_units = hp.Int('numeric_units', min_value=32, max_value=256, step=32)
hp_dropout = hp.Float('dropout', min_value=0.1, max_value=0.5, step=0.1)
hp_learning_rate = hp.Float('learning_rate', min_value=1e-4, max_value=1e-2, sampling='log')
# Girdi tanımlamaları
text_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_token_size,), dtype="int32", name="text_input")
numeric_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(26,), name="numeric_input")
# Debugging Embedding Layer Output
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=text_input)
print("Text input Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=numeric_input, outputs=numeric_input)
print("Numeric input Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

text_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(224, activation='relu')(text_input)

# Debugging Text Dense Layer Output
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=text_dense)
print("Text Dense Layer Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

# Embedding katmanı
embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=224,#vocab_size,
    output_dim=224,  # Embedding boyutu sabit
    #input_length=max_token_size
)(text_dense)

# Debugging Embedding Layer Output
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=embedding_layer)
print("Embedding Layer Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

# Text Pipeline
text_dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(224, activation='relu')(embedding_layer)

# Debugging Text Dense Layer Output
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=text_dense1)
print("Text Dense Layer 1 Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

text_batch_normalization = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(text_dense1)

# Debugging Text Dense Layer Output
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=text_batch_normalization)
print("Text Batch Normalization Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

text_dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(hp_dropout)(text_batch_normalization)

temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=text_dropout)
print("Text Dropout Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

# Numeric Pipeline
numeric_input_reshaped = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((26,))(numeric_input)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=numeric_input, outputs=numeric_input_reshaped)
print("Numeric Reshape Layer Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

numeric_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(224, activation='relu')(numeric_input_reshaped)

# Debugging Numeric Dense Layer Output
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=numeric_input, outputs=numeric_dense)
print("Numeric Dense Layer Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

#flattened_numeric_input = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(numeric_input)
embedding_layer_numeric = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=224,
    output_dim=224,  # Embedding boyutu sabit
    #input_length=max_token_size
)(numeric_dense)

# Debugging Embedding Layer Output
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=embedding_layer_numeric)
print("Embedding Layer Numeric Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

numeric_dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(224, activation='relu')(embedding_layer_numeric)

# Debugging Numeric Dense Layer Output
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=numeric_input, outputs=numeric_dense1)
print("Numeric Dense Layer 1 Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

numeric_batch_normalization = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(numeric_dense1)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=numeric_input, outputs=numeric_batch_normalization)
print("Numeric Batch Normalization Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

numeric_dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(hp_dropout)(numeric_batch_normalization)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=numeric_input, outputs=numeric_dropout)
print("Numeric Dropout Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

# Birleştirme
combined = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([text_dropout, numeric_dropout])

# Debugging Concatenated Layer Output
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined)
print("Concatenated Layer Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

# Global Max Pooling ile boyut düşürme
combined_pooled = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(combined)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_pooled)
print("Concatenated GlobalMaxPooling Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

# Combined Pipeline
combined_dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(combined_pooled)

# Debugging Combined Dense Layer 1 Output
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined_dense1)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_dense1)
print("Combined Dense Layer 1 Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

combined_batch_normalization = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(combined_dense1)
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined_batch_normalization)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_batch_normalization)
print("Combined Batch Normalization Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

combined_dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(hp_dropout)(combined_batch_normalization)
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined_dropout)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_dropout)
print("Combined Dropout Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

combined_dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(combined_dropout)

# Debugging Combined Dense Layer 2 Output
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined_dense2)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_dense2)
print("Combined Dense Layer 2 Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

combined_batch_normalization1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(combined_dense2)
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined_batch_normalization1)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_batch_normalization1)
print("Combined Batch Normalization 1 Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

combined_dropout1= tf.keras.layers.Dropout(hp_dropout)(combined_batch_normalization1)
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined_dropout1)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_dropout1)
print("Combined Dropout 1 Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

combined_dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(combined_dropout1)

# Debugging Combined Dense Layer 3 Output
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined_dense3)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_dense3)
print("Combined Dense Layer 3 Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

combined_dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(hp_dropout)(combined_dense3)
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=combined_dropout2)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=combined_dropout2)
print("Combined Dropout2 Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

# Çıkış Katmanı
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(combined_dropout2)

# Debugging Output Layer Shape
#temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=output)
temp_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[combined], outputs=output)

print("Output Layer Shape (Static):", temp_model.output_shape)

# Model Derleme
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, numeric_input], outputs=output)
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

return model

Error Logs:
Despite verifying dimensions throughout the model using debug print statements, I get the following error when the model starts training:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Functional.call(). Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1149, but received input with shape (None, 26)
Debug Logs: Here are the layer dimensions printed during model building:
Text input Shape (Static): (None, 1149) Text Dense Layer Shape (Static): (None, 224) Embedding Layer Shape (Static): (None, 224, 224) Text Dense Layer 1 Shape (Static): (None, 224, 224) Text Batch Normalization Shape (Static): (None, 224, 224) Text Dropout Shape (Static): (None, 224, 224) Numeric input Shape (Static): (None, 26) Numeric Reshape Layer Shape (Static): (None, 26) Numeric Dense Layer Shape (Static): (None, 224) Embedding Layer Numeric Shape (Static): (None, 224, 224) Numeric Dense Layer 1 Shape (Static): (None, 224, 224) Numeric Batch Normalization Shape (Static): (None, 224, 224) Numeric Dropout Shape (Static): (None, 224, 224) Concatenated Layer Shape (Static): (None, 224, 448) Concatenated GlobalMaxPooling Shape (Static): (None, 448) Combined Dense Layer 1 Shape (Static): (None, 256) Combined Batch Normalization Shape (Static): (None, 256) Combined Dropout Shape (Static): (None, 256) Combined Dense Layer 2 Shape (Static): (None, 128) Combined Batch Normalization 1 Shape (Static): (None, 128) Combined Dropout 1 Shape (Static): (None, 128) Combined Dense Layer 3 Shape (Static): (None, 64) Combined Dropout2 Shape (Static): (None, 64) Output Layer Shape (Static): (None, 1)

I suggest that you clean the code shown here which is very difficult to read with all the degugging tests. Do you get the error on the fit() instruction? show the line where the error happens. What is the size of data passed to fit ?
